# Cygwin on Windows - paste output limited to 80 columns

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, paste

I am using this command line with cygwin on windows 7 to merge 32400 files in only 1 column, in a 32400 columns file:

paste ./view{0..360..3}view{0..90..5}/tally_f8_1stcol.txt | column -s $'\t' -t > mod_profs_cm.txt

When I run this I get several errors like this "column: line 360 is too long, output will be truncated" and the resulting output (mod_profs_cm.txt) only comes with 80 columns.

I tried to use COLUMNS=40000 and set columns 40000 without any success.

How can I increase the columns of the output file?

Thanks

Comment: is `column` needed? paste by default uses tab separator..

Comment: I removed it and I don't have the problem anymore! Thank you so much!